# How do I patch cygwin to resolve the shellshock vulnerability?

Tags: cygwin, shellshock

I have cygwin installed on my computer and would like to make sure that I'm secured from the shellshock vulnerability.  How do I patch cygwin to fix the shellshock vulnerability?

Comment: Just install the lastest cygwin bash - it was recently updated to fix this and other issues see [Updated: bash-4.1.17-9](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2014-10/msg00015.html)

Answer (score 3):

The shellshock vulnerability affects the bash package.  An update of bash is required to resolve this.  According to the [bash update channels](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2014-09/msg00033.html), version 4.1.10-4 and below are NOT patched.  Version 4.1.12-5 and above are:

> A new release of bash, 4.1.12-5, has been uploaded and will soon reach a mirror near you; leaving the previous version of 4.1.10-4 on
>   32-bit, and
>   4.1.11-2 on 64-bit.
>
> NEWS:
>   ===== 
>   This is a minor rebuild which picks up an upstream patch to fix CVE-2014-6271.  Left unpatched, a vulnerable version of bash could
>   allow arbitrary code execution via specially crafted environment
>   variables, and was exploitable through a number of remote services, so
>   it is highly recommended that you upgrade.

---

### To check the version of your bash in cygwin use the following command:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

You'll get and output similar to the following:

```
4.1.17(9)-release
```

### To update the bash shell in cygwin:

1. Download the installer and run as you would normally do.
2. In the "Select Packages" dialog, select base --> bash (for the bleeding edge version select `Exp`):

   [image: Cygwin Setup - Select Packages]
3. Proceed through installation
4. Launch cygwin and use the same command above to make sure that the version was updated.